# How to translate 'a fun little distraction'?

Tags: translation, phrase-request, phrases

How do I translate this phrase into Korean?

> This mobile game not anything big, just *a fun little distraction* to pass your time
>   on the subway.

Google translate shows that this is

> 이 모바일 게임은 지하철에서 시간을 통과하는 큰 아무것도, 그냥 재미 좀 산만하지 않습니다.

which doesn't look like it makes sense; the same thing entered in naver translate shows the following translation:

> This mobile game is anything passing through the big time, not just
>   for fun, kind of distractions in the subway.

fun little distraction is translated as 재미 좀 산만 which also doesn't sound correct. What is the best way to translate this into Korean maintaining it's meaning?

Or in other words, for translating this sentence:

This mobile game is fun little distraction distraction to pass your time on the subway.

이 모바일 게임은 지하철 탈때 시간을 보내는 ___이다.

What would be the best phrase to go in the blank, or is it necessary to restructure the sentence to keep the same meaning?

Literal translations, possible common ways to imply this as well sample sentences would be helpful.

EDIT:

It is a fun little distraction.

이것은 재미있는 작은 오락거리다.

Does this sentence sound natural? Can it be used in a sentence as shown below:

I don't use Internet for business, it's just a way to pass the time for me.
저는 인터넷은 일하러 사용하지 않는데,  그것은 그냥 재미있는 작은 오락거리예요.

Answer (score 6):

I'm Korean and I am not good at English! Sorry for that.

> 이것은 재미있는 작은 오락거리다.
>
> 저는 인터넷은 일하러 사용하지 않는데, 그것은 그냥 재미있는 작은 오락거리예요.

Yes, both sentences sound natural to me. It's little awkward, but there is nothing wrong.

Maybe you could try:

> 저는 인터넷을 일할 때 사용하진 않아요. 주로 놀 때 사용하죠.

It is proper since we usually explain '오락거리' itself rather than explaining the usage of internet with '오락거리'. But both are good.

In Korean, there is no word implying both 'distracting' and 'something to play with' at the same time. So I think that is the reason for the poor translation from Google and Naver.

If you want to translate the following sentence to Korean:

> This mobile game is not anything big, just a fun little distraction to pass your time on the subway.

the following sentence would be better:

> 이 모바일 게임은 그리 대단한 것은 아니지만, 지하철에서의 지루한 시간을 함께할 재밌는 오락거리입니다.

Comment: No need to apologise for being Korean! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Warm welcome to Korean SE. As our help center page states, [Don't worry about making a few mistakes: other community members can help with corrections if you are not as strong in that language.](http://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) We are here to help you. Hope to see you often.

Comment: I've just edited your post. I tried to keep your words as much as possible. Please take a look. You can see what has been edited by clicking on **edited x minutes ago** just above my username at the bottom of your answer.

Comment: Regarding the last of your block quotes, I think when OP wrote, "not anything big," he meant more to diminish the time commitment (implied through the size of the game—whether its world, or controls, or involvement), not diminish the fun or greatness. My Korean isn't strong, but I thought "대단" was more to do with that latter kind of qualitative greatness. Something more to do with size might fit better.

Answer (score 5):

You could consider using '[심심풀이](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=24149500)' which means:

> 심심함을 잊고 시간을 보내기 위하여 어떤 일을 함. 또는 그런 일. (Literally) doing something to kill (spend) some time (시간을 보내다) and forget boredom (심심함을 잊다). Or such an action.

For example:

> 이 모바일 게임은 지하철에서 시간을 보내기 위해 하는 **심심풀이**예요.

'심심' is the stem of the adjective '[심심하다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=24147301&directAnchor=s243748p431265d501410)' which means:

> 하는 일이 없어 지루하고 재미가 없다. (Literally) bored without anything to do.